# Windows 8 private application submition

Tags: windows-8

I am new to Windows 8 development, I am having one application which is already running in the i-pad (ios). I want to convert same application into Windows Store apps as this is the client requirement. So do i need to follow the design guidelines for such legacy application? Or I can just follow the same UI which is been developed in i-pad. Is this accepted by Microsoft for Windows Store apps certification ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft's guidelines, it should not be accepted.

However, some such applications have appeared in the Windows Store in the past, so it's not completely impossible. I would not bet on it though.

And if your app is a game, the guidelines are less strict.

All the user experience (including design) guidelines are referenced [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465424.aspx).

And there is a [UX checklist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg126259.aspx) to make sure you confort to them.

Comment: But I am not able to find any design restriction in the Windows Store app certification http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx

Comment: Have a look at the UX guidelines http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465424.aspx and the UX checklist http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg126259.aspx